# Outputting text into input field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to press a button which outputs text in an input field. the function is to output text "x" into input field upon press, which is set to read only. only js and html allowed. Here's what i got so far in HTML and js:

```
 <button id="button4" onclick="output()">Hokus Pokus</button>
 <input id="printoutput" readonly="true" type="text">
```

js:

```
function output() {

document.getElementById("printoutput").innerHTML = "x";

}
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: Oh my, that was a very obvious oversight on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. did this:

```
function output() {

document.getElementById("printoutput").innerHTML = "x";

}
```

When it should be:

```
function output() {

document.getElementById("printoutput").value = "x";

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this and it works like a charm:

```js
function output() {

document.getElementById("printoutput").value = "x";

}
```

```html
 <button id="button4" onclick="output()">Hokus Pokus</button>
<input id="printoutput" readonly="true" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of the input, not the inner html

```js
document.getElementById("printoutput").value = "x";
```

```html
<button id="button4" onclick="output()">Hokus Pokus</button>
 <input id="printoutput" readonly="true" type="text">
```